# Not able to select the audio button in Github Captcha

Tags: python-3.x

Please I'm trying to do a python-selenium automation for Github signup.
I am not able to locate the selector for the audio button.
The below code snippet is not working:

```
sleep(5)
iframe = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0]
print(iframe)
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
browser.implicitly_wait(delayTime)

audioBtn = browser.find_element('.audioBtn.metaTooltipRight')
```

I also tried using:

`audioBtn = browser.find_element_by_class_name('fc_meta_audio_btn')`

But I am getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .fc_meta_audio_btn
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be. What's the meaning of a captcha if a Python script can solve it?